# How to center an image and make its position fixed at time of resizing in a responsive page using bootstrap

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I have tried to create a responsive coming soon page with the above image.I need to create a col_12 at centre of the page and have to position an image just outside the container top.While resizing the image position getting changed from width:760px.how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="all"/>

</head>

<body style="background:#9ed8f0;"> 
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:225px; background:#fff;">
<div class="container">
<center>
<img src="images/le1.png" alt="" style="margin-top:-121px; max-width:100%;">
</center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: I have uploaded the image. Please check it.My image dimension is 710px*356px

Comment: If you can, it would be really helpful for us all if you put what you've done so-far up online somewhere that we can see it. [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/) is good for sharing snippets of HTML/CSS.  With that, I'm positive somebody here will be able to quickly advise you.

Comment: Hi i have updated the code in Code Pen.http://codepen.io/priyatek/pen/crfmJ

Comment: Maybe this will help you

    http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/52VtD/750/